# How to fill up a limited quantity of characters in the middle of rows in a data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like to add a specific number of '0' in the middle of the rows to complete and keep a format (future matching use with another data frame).

I have a part of the data frame as follow,

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c("model03", "model07", "model011", "model019", "model0194"))
```

And I would like to get the result as like below,

[image]

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a combination of `paste0` and `str_pad` and `str_extract`:

```
library(stringr)
paste0("model", str_pad(str_extract(df$ID, "[1-9]+"), 4, "left", "0"))
[1] "model0003" "model0007" "model0011" "model0019" "model0194"
```

Here we perform three transformations:

- first, we `str_extract`the digits that are not `0`
- then, we `str_pad` the string to `4` characters with `0` filling up
- finally, we `paste0`the string `model`and the result of the previous operations together

Answer (score 2):

It should be concatenated with `c` and if these are not object name, then quote  it

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c('model03', 'model07', 'model011', 
    'model019', 'model0194'))
```

If the output needs to be formatted

```
df$ID <- sprintf('%s%04d', sub("\\d+", "", df$ID), readr::parse_number(df$ID))
df$ID
#[1] "model0003" "model0007" "model0011" "model0019" "model0194"
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe there is an easier way of doing this but here is a solution:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)

df %>% 
  separate(ID, c("model", "digit"), nchar("model")) %>%
  mutate(digit = str_pad(digit, 4, "left", "0")) %>%
  unite(ID, c(model, digit))

          ID
1 model_0003
2 model_0007
3 model_0011
4 model_0019
5 model_0194
```